# How do I get the hex code to show in the display? When I press the change color I want the Hex code to display on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the hex code to show up in the background color changer I made. Can I use `document.getElementById`?  Here is my code.  I want the Hex code to display when I press the Change Color button?  Would I use an array to do this or what would be the best option to use?  I trying, to just get better at JS I am really struggling with this so any help would be helpful.

```js
function bcc() {
  const color = document.getElementById('changeColor');
  color.style.color = newColor;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(219, 219, 161);
}

h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#button {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 0 45em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Background Color Changer</h1>
<h2>RGB Color: </h2>
<br>
<p id="changeColor">
  <button onclick="bcc()">Click to change color</button>
</p>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here

Comment: I just want to be able to display the hex code when the user clicks on change color.

Answer (score 2):

First, add an ID to the element where you want to display the color, like so:

```
<h2 id="color">RGB Color: </h2>
```

Then, change your JS function to this:

```
function bcc() {

  const color = document.getElementById('color');
  const backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(document.body ,null).getPropertyValue('background-color');

  color.innerHTML = "RGB Color: " + backgroundColor;

}
```

This will give you: `RGB Color: rgb(219, 219, 161)`

Comment: That just gives me the one color of rgb(219, 219, 161), when I click the Click to change the color nothing happens.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you meant to change is the backgroundColor attribute. `color` is the color of the text not of the background. You also want to put the `id` attribute on your button if that is the background you want to change. I don't think you need need the `<p>` anchor around your button. I tried to find a solution to your problem below

```js
function bcc() {

    const color = document.getElementById('changeColor');

    color.style.backgroundColor = 'black';

}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(219, 219, 161);
}

h1,
h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

#button {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 0 45em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Background Color Changer</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="background.css">
</head>

<html>
<body>

    <h1>Background Color Changer</h1>
    <h2>RGB Color: </h2>

    <br>
    <p>
        <button id="changeColor" onclick="bcc()">Click to change color</button>
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please don't hide your code on another site. Include your code in a Stack Snippet (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) so that everyone can share.

Comment: I have updated my message to follow your recommandation